# How can I get Google Chrome + Authy app to stick on my desktop?

Tags: google-chrome, google

Sorry, I am an absolute tyro, I do not understand much of the jargon. My question is simple: I download google. It appears as google-chrome-current_amd64.deb. It does not show as an icon. When I click, I get google-chrome-stable and an install button. Nothing seems to happen. I need it and the Authy app to initiate 2-step authentication. What now?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing chrome from terminal. It's easy. Open the Downloads folder (or where you downloaded the crhome deb file) and Right Click, Select "Open in Terminal". A Terminal Window will be display.

Write this command and Press Enter:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-current_amd64.deb
```

It will prompt you to enter password. Enter your password and Press Enter.
Make sure you have admin(sudo) privileges.

Comment: Many thanks, but after Right Click, there is no option "Open in Terminal".  No Terminal Window displays.  I am no further forward. TonyB.

Comment: Suddenly, I see another box for google-chrome_current_amd64, no date, on my computer.  I right click and obtain the Terminal window. I enter sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-current_amd64.deb. I am prompted for password. The only possibility does not work.

Comment: I am the administrator, it is my personal desktop computer.

Comment: I have found the right(?) password. I get this error message:dpkg: error processing archive google-chrome-current_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-current_amd64.deb